# Хранение и обновление xml в виде текста в БД на mysql

Tags: mysql, xml

Столкнулся со странным решением хранения данных в системе в виде xml в полях типа longtext. Странное оно с точки зрения организации самой базы данных, что не суть вопроса. 
Проблемы начались при попытке обновления данного поля - необходимо было заменить несколько узлов xml-структуры.
Схема работы банальна:

```
SELECT -> (замена значения) -> UPDATE
```

*(Промежуточный этап требует дополнительных обращений к базе)*
Исходный фрагмент структуры:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<goods><good pm_id="2" id="3231" cat_id="565">
    <p_title><![CDATA[Текст]]></p_title>
    <p_count>3</p_count>
    <p_ext_id></p_ext_id>
    ...
```

Подготовка строки к запросу и сам запрос:

```
      ...
      $xmlasstring = $xmlobj->asXML();
      $xmlasstring = str_replace("\n","",$xmlasstring);
      $xmlasstring = str_replace("\t","",$xmlasstring);
      $xmlasstring = str_replace('"',"'",$xmlasstring);
      $xmlasstring = str_replace('> </','></',$xmlasstring);
      mysqli_query($db_connection, 
                   "UPDATE `table1` SET `p`={$xmlasstring} WHERE `id`={$pid}");
```

Полученный после обработки и экранирования фрагмент для передачи в запрос UPDATE:

```
<?xml version=\'1.0\'?>
<goods>
<good pm_id=\'2\' id=\'3231\' cat_id=\'565\'>
<p_title><![CDATA[Текст]]></p_title>
<p_count></p_count>
<p_ext_id></p_ext_id>
...
```

На все попытки запихнуть измененную строку ответ один:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=<?xml version=\'1.0\'?><goods><good pm_id=\'2\' id=\'3231\' cat_id=\'565\'><p_' at line 1
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Хотелось бы понять, что не устраивает SQL при обработке запроса, ведь все спецсимволы вроде как экранированы.

Comment: возможно, где-то по пути запрос представляется в виде `update ... set ... = '<?xml ...'` и ваши одинарные кавычки всё «рушат». попробуйте заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные (сначала без обратного слэша, потом вместе с ним).

Comment: а, стоп. а у вас в вашем же вызове *mysqli_query* строка, подставляемая вместо `{$xmlasstring}`, заключена в кавычки? если нет, заключите.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, большое спасибо, действительно в этой детальке вся собака и была зарыта!

Comment: значит, оформляю в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверьте, заключена ли в кавычки строка, подставляемая вместо `{$xmlasstring}` в вызове `mysqli_query()`.

и если нет — заключите.